# What are the finite fields for which -1 is not a square?

Tags: finite-fields

What are the finite fields for which $-1$ is not a square? Of course they are of the form $\mathbb{F}_q$, with $q=p^r$, where $p$ prime, such that $p \neq 2$ and $p \equiv 3\pmod 4$. This, I remember from my good old Algebra courses. But for which values of $r$ is $-1$ not a square? For instance, if $r=2$, then by adjoining a root of $-1$ to $\mathbb{F}_p$, we get a field isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ containing a square root of minus $1$. So $r \neq 2$ also. I can probably rule out more cases this way, but, what is the general answer please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a field must *not* contain $\mathbf F_{p^2}$. Hence it is necessarily a field $\mathbf F_{p^r}$ with $r$ *odd* (and $p\equiv 3\mod 4$), since $\mathbf F_{p^r}\subset\mathbf F_{p^s}$ if and only if $r\mid s$.

Comment: yes but is the condition r odd sufficient for minus 1 not to be a square?

Comment: I think so:  if $\mathbf F_{p^r}$ contains a square root of $-1$ it contains (a copy of) $\mathbf F_{p^2}$ , so $r$ is even.

Answer (score 10):

A square root of $-1$ is an element of order $4$ in the group of units, $\mathbb{F}_q^*$. What do you know about this group, how many elements does it contain, which structure does it have? This will allow you to answer then exactly there is an element $i$ of order $4$. Once you have that, it will be easy to show $i^2 = -1$ as claimed.

Remark: Don't forget about the tricky case of $p=2$. Here, $-1=1 = 1^2$...

Comment: ah yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you are right.

Here is how you can prove for $q=p$ prime.

Consider the morphism $x\mapsto x^2\in \mathbb F_p$ for $p\ne 2$, considering its kernel, you can show that there is

$$\frac{p-1}2$$

squares in $\mathbb F_p^*$.

Then let's define

$$X:=\{x\in \mathbb F_p^*,\ x^{(p-1)/2}=1\}.$$

You can show that all squares are in $X$, and since $\mathbb F_p$ is a field, $\vert X\vert \leqslant \frac {p-1}2$.

So $X$ contain all the non-null squares.

And you have:

$$-1\in X\iff \frac{p-1}2\equiv 0\pmod 4\iff p\equiv 1\pmod 4.$$

Comment: Nice proof! Thank you. Somehow these things used to be more complicated and longer when I was a student. It is a nice short proof.

Comment: @Malkoun Yes, bad typo indeed. I made myself the same comment when I first discovered this proof!

Comment: nice proof. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: By the way, does your method give something interesting, for the map $x \mapsto x^n$, where $n | (p-1)$?

Comment: @Malkoun No idea, I will think about it.

Comment: yes I think it does, for say $F_q$, where $q = p^r$, $p$ prime, and we consider the map $x \mapsto x^n$, where $n | (q-1)$, for $x \in F_q^*$. Assuming the field $F_q$ contains all $n$'th roots of unity, then your argument gives that -1 is an $n$'th power iff $q \equiv 1$ (mod 2n), right?

Comment: @Malkoun I think it does, but it does not seem obvious to me that $\mathbb F_q$ contain all $n$'th roots of unity.

Comment: @Malkoun This question interested me a lot, I have asked what we discussed as another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328889/about-nth-rooth-of-1-in-a-finite-field