# About $n$'th rooth of $-1$ in a finite field

Tags: prime-numbers, finite-fields, roots-of-unity

*This question is based on [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328378/what-are-the-finite-fields-for-which-1-is-not-a-square) from @Malkoun, and more specifically the comments.*

**Context.**

Let's recall the following proof which shows that $-1$ is a square if $\mathbb F_p$ for $p\ne 2$ if, and only if, $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Consider the morphism $x\mapsto x^2\in \mathbb F_p$ for $p\ne 2$, considering its kernel, you can show that there is

$$\frac{p-1}2$$

squares in $\mathbb F_p^*$.

Then let's define

$$X:=\{x\in \mathbb F_p^*,\ x^{(p-1)/2}=1\}.$$

You can show that all squares are in $X$, and since $\mathbb F_p$ is a field, $\vert X\vert \leqslant \frac {p-1}2$.

So $X$ contain all the non-null squares.

And you have:

$$-1\in X\iff \frac{p-1}2\equiv 0\pmod 4\iff p\equiv 1\pmod 4.$$

**The question.**

Let's take $n$ such that $n\mid p-1$.

We want to extend the previous proof to get information about when $-1$ is a $n$'th power in $\mathbb F_p$.

I think that if $\mathbb F_p$ contain all $n$'th roots of $1$, then this argument shows that

$$-1\text{ is a $n$-th power } \iff p\equiv 1\pmod {2n}.$$

> How can we characterize the primes $p$ such that $\mathbb F_p$ contain all $n$'th roots of unity?

Comment: $p\equiv1\pmod{n}$.

Comment: yes, Lord Shark the Unknown is right, because $F_p^*$ is cyclic. So the condition that $F_p$ contains all $n$'th roots of unity is automatically satisfied, by just assuming that $n | (p-1)$. Good.

Comment: Note that if $n$ is odd, then -1 is clearly an $n$'th power. The condition $p\equiv 1$ (mod 2n) is also trivially satisfied since $p$ is odd.