# How to define a branch cut for the square root function over prime characteristic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, radicals, riemann-surfaces, branch-cuts

I was wondering about the following. Let $k$ denote an algebraically closed field. If it helps, I will take $k = \overline{F}_p$, meaning the algebraic closure of the finite field $F_p$ with $p$ elements, where $p$ is prime. One can also assume that $p$ is odd, for the sake of this question.

Over $\mathbb{C}$, one can define a "branch cut" for the square root function by removing $0$ and the negative real axis. This has the advantage that one can then pick a square root of $z$ in a consistent way.

Working now over $k$ as above, is there a way to define a "branch cut" for the (multivalued) square root function $z \mapsto \sqrt{z}$, for $z \in k$?

I am wondering whether this could be done in a sensible way, so that after removing the cut, the square root function can be defined as a single-valued function, and should be "continuous" in some sense.

Edit 1: in the case where $p \equiv 3 \,(\operatorname{mod} 4)$, in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q = p^r$, and $r$ is odd, so that $-1$ is not a square in $\mathbb{F}_q$ (see [What are the finite fields for which -1 is not a square?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328378/what-are-the-finite-fields-for-which-1-is-not-a-square)), let $S_q$ denote all non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$ which are squares in $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then given any $y \in S_q$, there are two solutions $\pm x$ of $x^2 = y$, exactly one of which lies in $S_q$.

We attempt to generalize this approach to any odd $p$, and any $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q=p^r$, where $r$ is any positive integer. We also denote by $S_q$ the set of non-zero elements which are squares. Let $\Delta_q$ be a set containing $(q-1)/2$ elements, such that given any non-zero element $z \in \mathbb{F}_q$, precisely one of $z$ and $-z$ lies in $\Delta_q$. Given $y \in S_q$, there are two solutions of $x^2 = y$, precisely one of which lies in $\Delta_q$.

If we can define the $\Delta_q$'s in such a way that they are compatible with the embeddings $\mathbb{F}_q \to \mathbb{F}_{q'}$ when $q'$ is a power of $q$, then I think we would be done, because things would carry over to the direct limit $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ (unless I am mistaken somewhere).

Does there exist such $\Delta_q$'s? Can one construct explicitly such a sequence of $\Delta_q$'s?

Edit 2: I could not find a "good" way to define a branch cut for the square root function over prime characteristic. The discreteness of such fields is the main culprit.

Comment: Well, for it to be continuous, it’ll have to be continuous in some neighborhood of (say) $1$. How do you propose to define continuity?

Comment: @Lubin, I don't insist on continuity per se. I'd be happy with weaker notions too (maybe etale?). I do insist on $1$-valuedness though.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but as an abstract group $\overline{ \mathbb {F}}_p^\times$ is isomorphic to the group of roots of unity in $\mathbb C^\times$ of order coprime to $p$. Under such identification, the branch cut you mention would just remove $-1$ (if $p\neq 2$).

Comment: @Marc Paul, I did not know that. I think it would answer my question. Could you maybe provide more details and if you want post it as an answer?

Comment: @MarcPaul, I don’t think your answer cuts it. You still have the problem that any element of $\overline{\Bbb F_p}^\times$ still has two square roots, and there is nothing whatever saying which one you choose; nor, given this choice, how that will help you making a choice the next time that will be consistent with your earlier choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a much better setting for asking your question. The unfortunate fact is that $\overline{\Bbb F_p}$ is irremediably discrete, and there’s virtually no way of saying that one element is close or closer to any other.

On the other hand, there is a good parallel to the complex numbers $\Bbb C$, namely the various $p$-adic fields and their complete extensions.

The field $\Bbb Q_p$ is the completion of the rationals with respect to a distance function in which two rationals are close if their difference is divisible by a high power of the prime number $p$. Specifically, if $a,b$ are integers both indivisible by $p$, you put
$$
\bigl\vert \frac abp^n\bigr\vert_p=c^{-n}\,,
$$
where $c$ is a fixed real number bigger than $1$. Conventionally, one takes $c=p$. Then, you define, for rational numbers $\lambda$ and $\mu$,
$$
d_p(\lambda,\mu)=\vert\lambda-\mu\vert_p\,.
$$
You can easily show that $d_p$ satisfies the triangle inequality and the other requirements for a metric. It happens that $\Bbb Q$ is not complete, but you can complete it to get an uncountable field $\Bbb Q_p$ that is nowhere near being algebraically closed. Many of the rules you learned in high school apply, like the convergence of a geometric series depending on the size of the common ratio: smaller than $1$ and you get a convergent series whose limit is given by the same formula you learned in high school.

**Why** have I gone into all this? Because in $\Bbb Q_p$ you have an unambiguous way of defining $\sqrt{z\,}$, as long as the numbers $z$ you’re rooting are close enough to $1$. Think of complex numbers near $1$ for a moment: they have square roots, consistently in the sense of the map $\sqrt{1+z}$ being continuous, and well defined for $z$ now being small enough. In particular, you have trouble if you try to define a complex square root function $\sqrt{1+z}$ when $z$ gets too near to $-1$, ’cause then you get to the weird point of the square-root function.

What’s a basic way of seeing that you have a good, consistent, continuous definition of $\sqrt{1+z}\,$? I offer the Binomial expansion
$$
(1+z)^{1/2}=1+\frac{\frac12}{1!}z+\frac{\frac12(\frac12-1)}{2!}z^2
+\frac{\frac12(\frac12-1)(\frac12-2)}{3!}z^3+\cdots\,,
$$
which is convergent for complex numbers $z$ with $\vert z\vert<1$. And the **wonderful fact** is that the very same series works in $\Bbb Q_p$, with the *same* condition on convergence when $p\ne2$, namely $\vert z\vert_p<1$ (for $p=2$, the condition is $\vert z\vert_2<\frac14$).

The unfortunate fact is that when you try to go outside this domain of convergence of the series, you’re essentially in the characteristic-$p$ situation of irremediable discreteness.

So I’d say that in the $p$-adic situation, there is something akin to the branch cut of the complex situation, but that you have to cut out not just something that’s of measure zero (like the negative real line), but something much bigger.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your interest in my question, and thank you for your detailed answer. Indeed, I don't know much about $p$-adic fields (only the definition), and I appreciate your answer. Investigating what happens over the $p$-adic fields was next on my list. Thank you.

Comment: I did not completely give up on the characteristic $p$ case though. I would like to think about it a little more.

Comment: I am somehow hoping to be able to define "rays" over characteristic $p$ using elements which are squares. I don't know if it will work out in the end or not. I am trying to work over $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q$ is a high power of $p$.

Comment: Ok, now I gave up on trying to define a "good" branch cut over characteristic $p$! Thank you for your help.